# C# - Class design & access modifiers

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

Given the following:

```
public abstract class Base
{
  // other stuff

  public static void StaticMethod()
  {
    PrivateMethod();
  }
  // here should be PrivateMethod() declaration somehow
}
public sealed class Derived: Base
{
  // other stuff

  public void InstanceMethod()
  {
    // call somehow PrivateMethod 
    PrivateMethod(); 
  }
}
```

I need to make use of PrivateMethod() from 2 different contexts (different assemblies). Once calling `Base.StaticMethod()`, and the second time by using an instance of the Derived class `d.InstanceMethod();`.

I am looking for a way how to design PrivateMethod() inside the Base class. Of course PrivateMethod() should not be visible outside the Base and Derived classes.

I was thinking something about "protected static PrivateMethod() {}" but I read I should not do that...

What do you recommend guys?

Comment: Maybe you can change requirements and in this case you'll find another solution, but in this particular case you have only one choice - protected static method.

Comment: Where do you read that you should not do that, and why should you not do that ?

Comment: I think here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/09/09/227332.aspx. But note, that Brad suggest "avoid" this, but "not use".

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peterhal/archive/2005/06/29/434070.aspx ... check also the last paragraph... maybe I misunderstand something there

Comment: I see you all recommending the same what I had in mind... so thank you very much for your support guys!

Comment: I will just leave it open few more hours in case somebody else comes with a different opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  protected static void PrivateMethod() {}
```

Is OK (apart form the name) and does what you require. You won't need `base.` when calling it from Derived.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. The thing is that I started this question after I checked this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peterhal/archive/2005/06/29/434070.aspx ... Maybe I missunderstand something there?

Comment: (After a quick read) The author regards this from a "encapsulation as security" perspective. Kind of valid for a lib designer but not relevant in an application. Point seems to be: You might as well be honest about it and make it public.

Comment: Thank you for rephrasing... :) I see what the article was trying to say now.

Answer (score 2):

I had never heard this before, so I went looking for something that said what you described. I found this article: [New Design Guideline: Avoid Protected Static](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/09/09/227332.aspx). However, it only talks about protected static field.

I don't think the article actually makes a good case for what it is trying to say. Rather than just describing how protected statics can lead to complications, it uses a very simple example of the base class designer not setting the right access flags for something that should not be accessed by everyone.

That being said, there is still a point that protected static can lead to complications. Protected static means that any subclass can call a method at any time. This can lead to thread safety concerns if the method is written naively. It seems like the article was written in a way that it conveys "Don't do it" rather than "If you need to do it, be careful."

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. Was really helpful! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could just call the public `StaticMethod()` from your derived class's `InstanceMethod()` ... since it indirects back to `PrivateMethod()` anyway. That way you can leave `PrivateMethod()` private. The implementation would be something like:

```
public abstract class Base
{
  // other stuff

  public static void StaticMethod()
  {
    PrivateMethod();
  }

  // here should be PrivateMethod() declaration somehow
  private static void PrivateMethod()
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
public sealed class Derived: Base
{
  // other stuff

  public void InstanceMethod()
  {
    // call somehow PrivateMethod 
    StaticMethod(); 
  }
}
```

PS: If there is need during StaticMethod to differentiate between a public caller or a derived class caller (from InstanceMethod) it could be either passed as parameter, or determined via reflection.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, although I think you wanted to point out something similar to "Artur Mustafin". InstanceMethod needs to call PrivateMethod, not StaticMethod